# How to resize a listbox in pysimplegui?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pysimplegui

I want to make the list box wider and higher but when I type:
`layout = [[General window elements], [sg.Listbox(key = "problems", values = ["Values"], size = (100, 200))]`.
But when I do this it moves the window out of the screen and I can't reach it. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Option `size`: (width, height), width = characters-wide, height = rows-high. It is clear that 200 as rows-high is too much to fit height of your screen, maybe ok for just 10 rows or 20 rows for it. The same, 100 characters-wide maybe also too wide to fit width of your screen if with large font.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, I thought it was pixels or something like that. Thank you :)